# Android - TextView not showing

Tags: java, android, textview, visibility, android-framelayout

I have a `TextView` that used to show on the screen, and did what I wanted. However, I streamlined some later code that repositions it with a touch to it's parent `FrameLayout`. Now, the `TextView` (named `angleView`) ceases to show on screen, but when I print out it's coordinates, it still works the same way. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code from my `onCreate()` method:

```
angleView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
angleView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
angleView.setText("0");
angleView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(SCREEN_WIDTH/20, SCREEN_HEIGHT/20));
```

and the code from the `FrameLayout`'s `onTouchListener`:

```
preview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float y = (centerPoint.getY() - event.getY() + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);
            float x = (centerPoint.getX() - event.getX());
            double angle = Math.atan(y/x);
            setAngleFieldData(event, angle, y, x);
            setFingerFollower(event, angle);
            setYMeasure(event, y);
            setXMeasure(event, x);
            setTextPositions(event, angle, y, x);
            Log.i("angleX", String.valueOf(angleView.getX()));
            Log.i("angleY", String.valueOf(angleView.getY()));
            return true;
        }

        private void setAngleFieldData(MotionEvent event, double angle, float y, float x){
            angleView.setText(String.valueOf(angle));
            angleView.setX(event.getX());
            angleView.setY(event.getY());
            if(isRadians) {
                if(x < 0 && y >= 0){
                    angleView.setText(String.valueOf(2 * Math.PI + angle));
                }
            }

        }
```

(the other methods are irrelevant, it used to be that all the code from the individual methods was in the `onTouch`.)

And in case you are wondering, yes, there is a:

```
preview.addView(angleView);
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT:** All of the code is inside the `onCreate()` method, inside an `Activity`.

Comment: is this inside an Activity? If (yes) don't use ApplicationContext, use the appropriate context. Then, for the sake of testing, force the TextView to be in a simple position to rule out all your math). Add LOGS everywhere to see the numbers.

Comment: would it be `new TextView(this)`?

Comment: If you are in an Activity, yes. If you're in a Fragment new TextView(getActivity())

Comment: also, i tried to set `angleView` to a hard-coded position, but it still didn't show up.

Comment: Wait, you're doing that in the Activity's onCreate() method? where do you do the preview.addview? and what is preview?

Comment: This is all within `onCreate()`. Sorry for not being clear about that earlier.

Comment: Check preview layout parameters, modify size, orientation or weight.

Comment: You might want to provide some more code and/or rollback to your previous version that was working and start again step by step, because it's hard to tell what the problem might be by just looking at this. Think how layout works, then try to follow the steps Android does to lay your widgets. You might be trying to add something that is still not possible to show/calculate or the dimensions may change later during the XML inflation to the point where your math ends up being wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the real reason why it didn't work (and I feel pretty stupid about it right now). If you look, you see that I set the params as SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT. Well, I initialized angleView before setting those two constants.

Good one, Jeeter :D

Comment: Still you should use a activity context in place of application context. Pls check the link in my answer as why you should use activity context.

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationContext` can't modify UI. Change:

```
angleView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

By:

```
angleView = new TextView(this);
```

Or if you are inside a Fragment:

```
angleView = new TextView(getActivity());
```

Comment: even when I change that it still doesn't work. It used to work just fine with getApplicationContext(), though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use activity context rather than application context

```
   angleView = new TextView(ActivityName.this);
```

Please check the answer by commonsware in the link below

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)